# Why is div bottom-border not showing in print out?

Tags: html, css

I am making a invoice generate web application. invoice is design with div, and row & cell are also border lined div.

All is good in the screen but when i send invoice to print, all the bottom border line are stack up in first page which are to be in second page, weird part is this only happens in second page only.

How can I fix this??

Here is HTML code for each row this keep looping for max number of rows needed.

```
<div class="container_24">
    <div id="invoice_frame" class="grid_18" style="padding:0px;">
<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 60; $x++) {
    <!-- Row Box <?php echo $x ?> -->
        <div class="rowBox rowBox-<?php echo $x ?> ti_box_WO_bottom" data-id="1" style="width:705px;">
           <div class="ti_box_onlyRight">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="ti_box_onlyRight">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="ti_box_onlyRight" style="width:378px;" align="left">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="ti_box_onlyRight">&nbsp;</div>
           <div style="margin:0px; margin-right:3px;">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
<?php } ?>

        <div class="ti_line">&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
          <div style="width:592px;" align="right"><strong>Total:&nbsp;</strong></div>
          <div class="ti_box" style="width:113px;" align="center"><?php echo $TInvoice_ROW['total_amount']; ?></div>
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <div style="width:592px;" align="right"><strong>Tax(GST) 6%:&nbsp;</strong></div>
          <div class="ti_box" style="width:113px;" align="center"><?php echo $TInvoice_ROW['gst_amount']; ?></div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div style="width:592px;" align="right"><strong>Grand Total:&nbsp;</strong></div>
          <div class="ti_box pv_total_box" style="width:113px; margin:0px;"><?php echo $TInvoice_ROW['total_grand']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div> 
          <div style="padding-top:6px;" align="right"><strong>Amount in words:&nbsp;</strong></div>
          <div style="width:559px; vertical-align:text-bottom; margin:0px;" align="left">
                <textarea name="inwords" disabled="disabled" readonly class="pv_textbox_WO_outline" id="inwords" style="width:580px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
.container_24 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#invoice_frame {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
} 

#invoice_frame div{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
} 

#invoice_frame div.ti_box_onlyRight {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #000;
    margin:0px !important; 
}
    
#invoice_frame div.ti_box_WO_bottom {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Are the div's empty? If so try adding a non-breaking space (&nbsp) in the div's. Also how is the "position" set for each div? Next I must assume that you're not using a "table" (which would make things simpler) so, for the divs in each row, is the "display" being set to "inline" or is each div got a top and left positioning?  You gave two rows of divs but the issue is about the entire page. More code would be useful. On a side note, `border: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: none;` is easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes I have given non breaking space in each div. Each div set inline-block and float to left no position is set. Ya i am not using tables its all div's. Will update the question with more code.

Comment: @Krik i have included other parts of the codes